# Images are not fitting in the Motorola Razr 4.7 screen

Tags: android

I am testing my app on different devices and on the Motorola Razr the images are smaller and the layout is not fitting correctly.

1. This device's screen size is categorized as normal. Just like the different devices I am testing on.
2. I put all my images in 5 different drawable folders(drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-tvdpi,drawable-xhdpi). Still the images are smaller...

Is there any way I can get the layout to fit just like the other devices? (HTC, Samsung etc)

EDIT:

I have an image 480X556   and I put it in the drawable-hdpi folder. In the XML I put the Image background width to--android:layout_width="320dp" . All is working fine on all "Normal" screens except for the 4.7 screen. I dont want to change the xml but add another image to a diffrent folder.
1) What folder should I move the new image too?
2) What width in the pixel should I give it in order for it to fit the screen without me touching the XML and leaving it on android:layout_width="320dp" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a `normal` screen on 4.7 inches, it'll use the resources in the `drawable-xhdpi` folder.

If you `mdpi` images are 48x48 pixels, your `xhdpi` images should be 96x96 pixels. You can use `drawable-nodpi` if you want the exact pixel size rather than the density size.

Comment: Michell thanks for the quick response! However I tried to copy all my images to the drawable-xhdpi. However, I am still getting the same result..Do I have to something in order for the system to look at the xhdpi folder? Or does it go there automatically?

Comment: The images have to be of higher resolution. You can't just copy the same images into different folders.

Comment: I changed the images resolution from 480 width to 640 width and placed in xhdpi folder...still same result I must be missing something here. Thanks!

Comment: That's not enough. The xhdpi resources are twice as large, like I wrote in the answer (48x48 to 96x96). mdpi = 1.0 scale, hdpi = 1.5 scale and xhdpi = 2.0 scale.

Comment: Sorry for being a pain but I edited the question to add more info Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't think you fully understand the concept of the `dp` unit. I'll give you an example. If you want to show a 320dp image on three different devices. If you're on a mdpi device, you need the image to be exactly 320 pixels wide (320 * 1). If you're on hdpi, it needs to be 480 pixels wide (320 * 1.5) and finally 640 pixels wide on a xhdpi device (320 * 2). The DPI is the scaling factor like I wrote in the above comment.